# Почему не возвращаются ошибки в параметрах функции?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Почему ts не ругается, если в типе я указал, что функция принимает 2 параметра, а в самой функци либо без параметров, либо 1, либо 2? Ведь я не указал, что параметр может принимать undefined "?"

```
type AA = (b: string, c: number) => void

const aa: AA = () => {
    // to do something
};

const aa2: AA = (b) => {
    // to do something
};

const aa3: AA = (b, c) => {
    // to do something
};
```

И только в таком случае - ошибка

> Type '(b: any, c: any, d: any) => void' is not assignable to type
> 'AA'.

```
const aa4: AA = (b, c, d) => {
    // to do something
};
```

И что нужно сделать, чтобы ts возвращал ошибку, если количество параметров не соответствует типу?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тип `AA` указывает, что функция принимает два параметра. Это означает, что **при вызове** данной функции **обязательно** нужно передать два аргумента.

Три дальнейших примера сохраняют в переменную с типом `AA` функции с меньшим количеством аргументов.

### Почему это работает?

Присваиваемые функции, определяют необходимое им количество аргументов (0, 1, 2). Тип `AA` **гарантирует**, что при вызове эти аргументы будут переданы. Поэтому и присваивать такие функции в переменную с типом `AA` можно.

### Почему не работает третий вариант?

Присваиваемая функция **требует** 3 аргумента. Однако тип `AA` может гарантировать только 2, таким образом, при вызове мог бы быть пропущен обязательный аргумент.

Поэтому присвоить такую функцию в переменную с типом `AA` нельзя.

---

TS проверяет, чтобы было передано как минимум **требуемое** количество аргументов при вызове. На данный момент ужесточить проверку нельзя.